# Using Cmake to just do ./genMakefiles && make -j4

Tags: c++, makefile, build, cmake

I'm trying to integrate CMake build on https://github.com/rgaufman/live555

It uses the traditional `./genMakefiles && make -j4` therefore I just need to create a `CMakeLists.txt` that does this, right?

*I know the right way would be to add all the cpp files and build everything but it's not my project and I'm not going to maintain it so the best way for this case would be to just integrate like I'm suggesting*

Here's my prototype:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(live555)

ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/live555
    COMMAND ./genMakefiles linux
    COMMENT "=================== Generating makefiles for linux"
    COMMAND make -j4
    COMMENT "=================== make..."
)
```

I didn't understand what is `OUTPUT` for. Isn't `OUTPUT` dictated by `make -j4`? Also, I did `cmake . && make`, see the output:

```
lz@vm:~/JSCam/src/jscam/live555$ cmake .
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/lz/JSCam/src/jscam/live555
lz@vm:~/JSCam/src/jscam/live555$ make
```

I can't either see the comments I added and files aren't being built.

Comment: Put those command into a script and call the script from the custom command.

Comment: @KhouriGiordano what the output is for? Do you know why I cannot put commands directly? I found examples that did exactly that

Comment: I had similar trouble doing this and putting everything into a script fixed it. Somewhere in the `CMakeFiles` folder is a makefile containing your custom command.

Comment: Consider what/if you gain with this approach. You introduce another dependency (CMake) but cannot use any of the advantages of CMake (platform independence; dependency checking; easy switching between compilers, build types, etc.; support for other build tools like Ninja; …). On the whole you add complexity for no gain at all. You’ll even confuse people who see a CMakeLists.txt and expect a proper CMake project. Imo either develop a proper CMake project and be prepared to maintain it, or don’t to it at all.

Comment: You shouldn't add the make call into your CMake configure run. That's plain wrong and against how CMake is supposed to work. CMake should only call / replace your genMakefiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CMake, if you need to build some other project which you are "not going to maintain", [ExternalProject_Add](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/module/ExternalProject.html) usually is a good choice:

> The `ExternalProject_Add` function creates a custom target to drive download, update/patch, configure, build, install and test steps of an external project

Its usage is quite simple:

```
include(ExternalProject) # Include definition of 'ExternalProject_Add' function

ExternalProject_Add(live555 # Name of the target. Could be any
    # Setup source directory
    SOURCE_DIR <path-to-directory-with-external-project>
    # Setup build directory. Here it is the same as source one.
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
    # Configuration step
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ./genMakefiles linux
    # Build step. It is actually `make`, but in a wise manner.
    BUILD_COMMAND ${CMAKE_MAKE_COMMAND}
    # Disable install step
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    )
```